# How to properly wrap input text and button elements side by side?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a search *input text* with a side by side *button*.

Here are the requirements:

1. Those elements should be absolute centered. Both vertical and horizontal.
2. The solution should work on IE8+ and good browsers.
3. In the browser default font-size is bigger, no text or graphic
   element should be hidden or misplaced on the user browser.

I believe I have no issues with vertical align part. Using *pseudo-element height: 100%; with display: inline-block;* technique.

I do have issues however, on placing the button element, side by side with the input text field, without any white gaps around.

Here's the **HTML**:

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div id="search-wrapper">
    <h3>Hello there</h3>
    <form action="" class="search-form">
      <input type="text" name="lorem" />
      <button type="submit">
        <span>Search</span> 
        <!-- should be a place to background image or icon font symbol.  -->       
      </button>    
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the **CSS**:

```
/* START - Absolute Centering */
#main-wrapper {
    text-align:center;
    background: yellow;
    height: 300px;
}

#main-wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#search-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 20px 20%;
}
/* END - Absolute Centering */

/* START - Input and Button Search - Side by Side */
.search-form {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid red;
    background: #fff;
}

.search-form input {
   font-size: 1.3em;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
}

.search-form button {
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top; /* no dice */
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uQh8D/

And here's a screenshot of ugly white parts that we wish to get rid of, as we see them on Chrome and on Firefox:

Chrome 34:

[image: chrome white space around button issues]

Firefox 28 (almost ok):

[image: firefox button bottom white space issues]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it solves the issue properly, I don't see anyone around me to kick me for being no semantic precise. (I do have a "useless" span already).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uQh8D/5/

Comment: @Bharadwaj, thanks a lot!. As we know, tables could be a pain to style later on. Wouldn't it be better to use display: tables instead. Or it's not relevant?

Comment: That's why I asked a question first.

Comment: I thought to meant display table when you refer to table. Sorry.

Comment: @Bharadwaj tables are only to be used for tabular data - never for layout - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy fix to this would be to use `box-sizing: border-box` but IEs support of this is only partial so I wouldn't be sure if it works in ie8 - you may have to find the -ms version for it to work.

[box-sizing: border-box example](http://jsfiddle.net/uQh8D/2/)

A more rounded solution could be to use the `display:table` as it should be supported back to IE 8

[display:table example](http://jsfiddle.net/uQh8D/4/)

Comment: Thanks Pete. I will go with the display:table thing. And, perhaps, I will use the same technique for vertical centered elements. Seems more consistent I believe. I will give it a try and let you know the results.

Comment: I always use display table for vertical alignment - seems a lot easier and more supported than display:flex

Comment: Seems to be ok: http://jsfiddle.net/w4jsY/ - Do you agree? Thanks for being around. Really. I was pulling my hair of for this one.